Light switch wiring to fixtures
Need help wiring fixture from switch.
I currently have a switch controlling light fixture 1. Attached photo shows the current wiring: white from fixture 1 to white from switch and black from fixture 1 to black of switch.  The light switch currently turns light fixture 1 on/off. I am trying to add light fixture 2 at the junction box. I have attached the future wiring with switch and fixtures 1 and 2 diagramed out. Based on the second diagram what wires would go together.

Rather than a drawing that cannot possibly be correct, please provide pictures of the actual wiring connections.

The circuit from the switch is a  switch loop that is no longer allowed by code.  You may still be able to use it, but rather than just color of wires, all the wire must be identified as Hot from the breaker, switched hot and neutral and grounds.


"Based on the second diagram what wires would go together"?

According to your diagram, this cannot be done with the current wiring configuration because your junction box does not have a neutral/grounded conductor. "Fixture 2" needs a *neutral/grounded conductor" to function.
The two wires (black and white) that leave "Fixture 1's" location and go to the switch (via the junction box) are a "hot" (constant power) and a "switched hot" return (power interrupted by the switch). The neutral is at "Fixture 1" but was not carried to the junction box or the switch. This used to be a very common wiring strategy called a "switch loop" or "switch leg".
